# JAVA Future isRunning?

Tags: java, web-applications, concurrency, future

From a future (java.util.concurrent.Future) is there any way to know if it's process is currently running? Im trying to build a view in a web app which shows the status of certain processes and I can only get from the future if it is done or was cancelled.

Comment: A `Future<V>` is an *Interface* - that completely depends on what is implementing that interface

Comment: are you able to edit the code of the class implementing future? as you might use events to know when the future starts to run.

Comment: I have that in mind but i was hoping if there is a simpler solution, since I have lots of diferrent type of processes and that would mean creating lots of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the point of a `Future`. The point is that it's a **promise** of a future result, hence the name. It makes no guarantees about how or when it will be run. It could be run on the current thread, on a different thread, or potentially in a different process I suppose. As such, it doesn't have any state beyond present or absent -- which is more or less the whole point. If you want to monitor the progress of some thread, you have to work at that lower layer of abstraction.

Comment: You were right, I finished adding a boolean with the current status of the instance (isRunning)

Answer (score 2):

What about `boolean isDone()`? It returns false, if its still running.
Otherwise you could start a thread who calls get() and blocks till it has finished. Then this thread could set a finished flag.

Comment: It also returns isDone() if is has not started.

Comment: it also returns "true" if it is in the queue

Comment: added another approach. get should also block, if it hasnt started.correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to determine if the future is in the queue, if that's what you want.

Comment: wouldnt returning true in case it didnt complete violate the contract of isDone(), which states returning true iff(!) it completed?

Comment: Actually you can determine if it is in the queue with isDone(). What you cant know (but i need to) is the know if it is in the queue and is currently running (first of the queue).